# Consulta de multiples tablas sobre una misma tabla

Tags: mysql

Hola buen dia mi problema es este:
Tengo una estructura de tablas parecida a esta:

```
table masterTable
+------------------------+
| Field                  |
+------------------------+
| id                     |
| idDoc                  |
| doc                    |
+------------------------+

table doc1
+------------------------+
| Field                  |
+------------------------+
| id                     |
| info                   |
+------------------------+

table doc2
+------------------------+
| Field                  |
+------------------------+
| id                     |
| info                   |
+------------------------+
```

Con ella pretendo que masterTable pueda sacar informacion de las tablas doc1, doc2 y otras doc mas 
comunicandose mediante el campo doc que sirve para identificar hacia que tabla irse a consultar. 
Suponiendo que masterTable tiene esta informacion
table masterTable

```
+-------------------
| id | idDoc | doc |
+----+--------------
|  1 |     1 |   1 |
|  2 |     1 |   2 |
|  3 |     2 |   2 |
|  4 |     3 |   2 |
|  5 |     2 |   1 |
+-------------------
```

Con este qry extraigo el campo info de las tablas doc:

```
SELECT 
    masterTable.id,
    docs.info
FROM masterTable
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        '1' as doc,
        id,
        info
    FROM doc1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        '2' as doc,
        id,
        info
    FROM doc1 
) docs ON docs.id = masterTable.idDoc 
    AND docs.doc = masterTable.doc
```

El comportamiento es correcto y logro sacar la informacion deseada, mi problema es que siento que en algun punto la tabla masterTable pueda crecer
tanto y consultar demasiadas tablas doc (al menos unas 10 ) y la consulta se vuelva pesada, existe alguna manera de hacer la estructura o el qry de manera mas eficiente o esta 
es la correcta?, muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: para tu situacion te recomendaria que hagas un buen uso de indices pues estos te ayudan a agilizar las busquedas, aca de dejo algo de informacion: [Introduccion a los indices](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/introduccion-a-indices-en-mysql/)

Comment: Me podrias explicar de que manera podrias aplicar indices para agilizar mi consulta?

Comment: Si las tablas doc pueden ser indeterminadas ¿desde una hasta cuántas?... me atrevería a decir que en vez de ver el problema desde el punto de vista de ¿cómo hago la consulta?, habría que plantearse cambiar el diseño de las tablas (si fuera posible). Por ejemplo, una sola tabla con todos los doc y una tabla asociativa que manejaría una relación muchos a muchos entre doc y MasterTable.

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar, exacto el problema seria o cambiar la estructura o el qry, el ejemplo seria correcto, el detalle es que como lo mencione al principio la estructura que muestro es una parecida al que estoy trabajando, en realidad las tablas doc son mucho mas complejas con referencia hacia otras tablas y no puedo unificarlas, masterTable solo necesita ciertos campos de cada una de ellas y las tablas doc lo maximo que pueden ser son 10.